# React Native application start throwing errors after using react-native-track-player both build and start

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, react-native-track-player

React Native application build was working recently, But now one critical package that I'm using as a part of the essential feature is started throwing errors on IOS build.

Following are the build error details, and after some search added a swift empty file to create a bridge but the results are still the same.

```
** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
    CompileSwiftSources normal x86_64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler (in target 'react-native-track-player' from project 'Pods')
    CompileSwift normal x86_64 /Users/c0d3/Projects/Zeefa/gem-mobile-app/node_modules/react-native-track-player/ios/RNTrackPlayer/Vendor/SwiftAudio/Classes/NowPlayingInfoController/NowPlayingInfoProperty.swift (in target 'react-native-track-player' from project 'Pods')
    CompileSwift normal x86_64 /Users/c0d3/Projects/Zeefa/gem-mobile-app/node_modules/react-native-track-player/ios/RNTrackPlayer/Models/PitchAlgorithms.swift (in target 'react-native-track-player' from project 'Pods')
    CompileSwift normal x86_64 /Users/c0d3/Projects/Zeefa/gem-mobile-app/node_modules/react-native-track-player/ios/RNTrackPlayer/Vendor/SwiftAudio/Classes/QueuedAudioPlayer.swift (in target 'react-native-track-player' from project 'Pods')
(4 failures)
```

Given is the react-native info response

```
System:
    OS: macOS 12.2.1
    CPU: (12) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz
    Memory: 162.65 MB / 16.00 GB
    Shell: 5.8 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 14.16.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.1/bin/node
    Yarn: Not Found
    npm: 6.14.12 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.1/bin/npm
    Watchman: Not Found
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.10.1 - /usr/local/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 21.2, iOS 15.2, macOS 12.1, tvOS 15.2, watchOS 8.3
    Android SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: Not Found
    Xcode: 13.2.1/13C100 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 17.0.1 - /usr/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 17.0.1 => 17.0.1 
    react-native: 0.64.0 => 0.64.0
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with XCODE 13, till now I didn't get any workaround but when downgrading XCODE back to 12 and doing the same build it is working as expected.

For anyone stuck with the same issue, Until getting a proper solution I would suggest getting a MAC machine in AWS so that you can switch to any version of the OS and do the build. Make sure to delete or STOP the machine once the build is done as it is too costly.

[https://aws.amazon.com/pm/ec2-mac](https://aws.amazon.com/pm/ec2-mac/?trk=84c3f96b-093a-4565-b95f-f2ea9aae408c&sc_channel=ps&sc_campaign=acquisition&sc_medium=ACQ-P%7CPS-GO%7CBrand%7CDesktop%7CSU%7CCompute%7CEC2%20Mac%7CEEM%7CEN%7CText%7CNon-EU&s_kwcid=AL!4422!3!525653303437!e!!g!!aws%20mac%20cloud&ef_id=Cj0KCQjwz7uRBhDRARIsAFqjulndoj1gSDHy2IS4GxT9sImzKDUrnG341ftDhKMP5MdATYVlX2wCLY0aAnqDEALw_wcB:G:s&s_kwcid=AL!4422!3!525653303437!e!!g!!aws%20mac%20cloud)

[image]